# Logitech Lua help needed

Tags: lua, scripting, macros, logitech-gaming-software

software = Logitech G hub

UPDATE

Okay! Thanks to some help this is where I'm at, Everything's working very nicely and as it should but now I face a new task and that is adding variations of each table for the slight changes to recoil when using scopes.
I could simple add more gun modes and make the changes required but I'd really like to make a way of using a key to toggle whether they are used or not, An idea I have floating around my head is for F9 and F10 to toggle between the scopes and when the toggle is off it will work with the code I already have. however I'm not sure this is possible, to my understanding I could use the lock keys (capslock, scrolllock, numlock) to make this work. initially I had the idea to have a toggle key that modifies the timing of the recoil sequence but unfortunately this is not an accurate solution.

What I'd like to do now is create 2/3 toggles that allow gun modes to switch between variable tables without having to add more guns

any help is greatly appreciated and that goes for any help I've received so far too

thanks

```
---GUN MODES---
local GUN1_Mouse = 8
local GUN1_Keyboard = nil

local GUN2_Mouse = 7
local GUN2_Keyboard = nil

local GUN3_Mouse = 9
local GUN3_Keyboard = nil

local GUN4_Mouse = nil
local GUN4_Keyboard = nil

local GUN5_Mouse = 5
local GUN5_Keyboard = nil

local GUN6_Mouse = nil
local CUSTOM_Keyboard = nil

local GUN7_Mouse = 4
local GUN7_Keyboard = nil

---RECOIL TABLES---
local recoil_table = {}
-------------------------------------
recoil_table["GUN1"] = {
    0, 6, 133,  
   -1, 6, 133,
   -1, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -3, 6, 133,
   -3, 6, 133,
   -3, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
   -4, 6, 133,
}

recoil_table["GUN1_crouch"] = {
    0, 3, 133,
   -1, 3, 133,
   -1, 3, 133,
   -1, 3, 133,
   -1, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -3, 3, 133,
   -3, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
}


-------------------------------------
recoil_table["GUN2"] = {
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
   0, 5.5, 120,
}

recoil_table["GUN2_crouch"] = {
    0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
   -0, 2.8, 120,
}


-------------------------------------
recoil_table["GUN3"] = {
    0, 3, 133,
   -1, 3, 133,
   -1, 3, 133,
   -1, 3, 133,
   -1, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -3, 3, 133,
   -3, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
   -2, 3, 133,
}

recoil_table["GUN3_crouch"] = {
   0, 2.5, 125,
   0, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   0.7, 2.5, 125,
   0.7, 2.5, 125,
   0.7, 2.5, 125,
   0.8, 2.5, 125,
   0.9, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   0.7, 2.5, 125,
   0.7, 2.5, 125,
   0.7, 2.5, 125,
   0.8, 2.5, 125,
   0.9, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
   1, 2.5, 125,
}

-------------------------------------
recoil_table["GUN4"] = {
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
   0, 3.4, 100,
}

recoil_table["GUN4_crouch"] = {
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
   0, 1.7, 100,
}

-------------------------------------
recoil_table["GUN5"] = {
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
   0, 2.4, 129,
}

recoil_table["GUN5_crouch"] = {
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
   0, 1.2, 129,
}

-------------------------------------
recoil_table["GUN6"] = {
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
   0, 3, 100,
}

recoil_table["GUN6_crouch"] = {
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
   0, 1.5, 100,
}

-------------------------------------
recoil_table["GUN7"] = {
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120, 
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120,
   0, 4.4, 120, 
}

-------------------------------------
recoil_table["GUN7_crouch"] = {
    0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
    0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
    0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
   -0, 2.2, 120,
}
---------------------------------------------------

local weapon

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == GUN1_Mouse) or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == GUN1_Keyboard) then
      weapon = weapon ~= "GUN1" and "GUN1"
      if not weapon then
         OutputLogMessage("OFF-GUN1\n")
         if IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      else
         OutputLogMessage("ON-GUN1\n")
         if not IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      end
   ------------- for adding another weapon -----------
   elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == GUN2_Mouse) or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == GUN2_Keyboard) then
      weapon = weapon ~= "GUN2" and "GUN2"
      if not weapon then
         OutputLogMessage("OFF-GUN2\n")
         if IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      else
         OutputLogMessage("ON-GUN2\n")
         if not IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      end
   ------------- for adding another weapon -----------
   elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == GUN3_Mouse) or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == GUN3_Keyboard) then
      weapon = weapon ~= "GUN3" and "GUN3"
      if not weapon then
         OutputLogMessage("OFF-GUN3\n")
         if IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      else
         OutputLogMessage("ON-GUN3\n")
         if not IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      end 
 ------------- for adding another weapon -----------
   elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == GUN4_Mouse) or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == GUN4_Keyboard) then
      weapon = weapon ~= "GUN4" and "GUN4"
      if not weapon then
         OutputLogMessage("OFF-GUN4\n")
         if IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      else
         OutputLogMessage("ON-GUN4\n")
         if not IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      end 
------------- for adding another weapon -----------
   elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == GUN5_Mouse) or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == GUN5_Keyboard) then
      weapon = weapon ~= "GUN5" and "GUN5"
      if not weapon then
         OutputLogMessage("OFF-GUN5\n")
         if IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      else
         OutputLogMessage("ON-GUN5\n")
         if not IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      end 
 ------------- for adding another weapon -----------
   elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == GUN6_Mouse) or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == GUN6_Keyboard) then
      weapon = weapon ~= "GUN6" and "GUN6"
      if not weapon then
         OutputLogMessage("OFF-GUN6\n")
         if IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      else
         OutputLogMessage("ON-GUN6\n")
         if not IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      end
 ------------- for adding another weapon -----------
   elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == GUN7_Mouse) or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == GUN7_Keyboard) then
      weapon = weapon ~= "GUN7" and "GUN7"
      if not weapon then
         OutputLogMessage("OFF-GUN7\n")
         if IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      else
         OutputLogMessage("ON-GUN7\n")
         if not IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      end 
   ---------------------------------------------------
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and weapon and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
      local recoil_sequence = recoil_table[weapon..(IsModifierPressed("lctrl") and "_crouch" or "")] or {}
      local x, y, tm = 0, 0, GetRunningTime()
      for j = 3, #recoil_sequence, 3 do
         local dx_10ms = recoil_sequence[j-2]
         local dy_10ms = recoil_sequence[j-1]
         local duration = recoil_sequence[j]
         repeat
            Sleep(10)
            if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
            local dt = math.min(GetRunningTime() - tm, duration)
            duration, tm = duration - dt, tm + dt
            x, y = x + dt/10 * dx_10ms, y + dt/10 * dy_10ms
            local int_x, int_y = math.floor(x), math.floor(y)
            x, y = x - int_x, y - int_y
            MoveMouseRelative(int_x, int_y)
         until duration == 0
         if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: example...
GUN1 1 = IRONSIGHTS
GUN1 0 + TOGGLE KEY 1 = GUN WITH HOLO
GUN1 + TOGGLE KEY 2 = GUN WITH ACOG SCOPE
with an output lcd message to show

Answer (score 0):

You should use function `GetRunningTime()` to check if it is time to change recoil direction.

```
---GUN MODES---
local AK47_Mouse = 8
local AK47_Keyboard = nil

------------- for adding another weapon -----------
local AnotherWeapon_Mouse = 7
local AnotherWeapon_Keyboard = nil
---------------------------------------------------

local SpeedX2Modifier_Mouse = nil
local SpeedX2Modifier_Keyboard = 1   -- key G1
local SpeedX2 = false


---RECOIL TABLES---
local recoil_table = {}

recoil_table["AK47"] = {
   -- down for 1 second
   0, 0.5, 1000,  -- delta_x_per_10ms, delta_y_per_10ms, duration_in_ms
   -- diagonal for 1 second
   -2, 4, 1000,
   -- it stops moving after 2 seconds (even if LMB is still pressed)
}

recoil_table["AK47_crouch"] = {
   -- down forever (until LMB is released)
   0, 2, math.huge,  -- math.huge means "very big number of ms"
}

recoil_table["AK47_reddot"] = {
   -- down forever (until LMB is released)
   0, 2, math.huge,  -- math.huge means "very big number of ms"
}


------------- for adding another weapon -----------
recoil_table["AnotherWeapon"] = {
   -- down for 1 second
   0, 0.5, 1000,  -- delta_x_per_10ms, delta_y_per_10ms, duration_in_ms
   -- diagonal for 1 second
   -2, 4, 1000,
   -- it stops moving after 2 seconds (even if LMB is still pressed)
}

recoil_table["AnotherWeapon_crouch"] = {
   -- down forever (until LMB is released)
   0, 2, math.huge,  -- math.huge means "very big number of ms"
}

recoil_table["AnotherWeapon_reddot"] = {
   -- down forever (until LMB is released)
   0, 2, math.huge,  -- math.huge means "very big number of ms"
}
---------------------------------------------------

local weapon

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == AK47_Mouse) or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == AK47_Keyboard) then
      weapon = weapon ~= "AK47" and "AK47"
      if not weapon then
         OutputLogMessage("OFF-Macro-AK47\n")
         if IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      else
         OutputLogMessage("ON-NoRecoil-AK47\n")
         if not IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      end
   ------------- for adding another weapon -----------
   elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == AnotherWeapon_Mouse) or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == AnotherWeapon_Keyboard) then
      weapon = weapon ~= "AnotherWeapon" and "AnotherWeapon"
      if not weapon then
         OutputLogMessage("OFF-Macro-AnotherWeapon\n")
         if IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      else
         OutputLogMessage("ON-NoRecoil-AnotherWeapon\n")
         if not IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
            PressAndReleaseKey("numlock")
         end
      end
   ---------------------------------------------------
   elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == SpeedX2Modifier_Mouse) or (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == SpeedX2Modifier_Keyboard) then
      SpeedX2 = not SpeedX2
      if not SpeedX2 then
         OutputLogMessage("OFF-SpeedX2\n")
      else
         OutputLogMessage("ON-SpeedX2\n")
      end
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and weapon and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
      local recoil_sequence = recoil_table[weapon..(
         IsKeyLockOn("capslock") and "_crouch" or
         IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") and "_reddot" or "")] or {}
      local x, y, tm = 0, 0, GetRunningTime()
      for j = 3, #recoil_sequence, 3 do
         local dx_10ms = recoil_sequence[j-2]
         local dy_10ms = recoil_sequence[j-1]
         if SpeedX2 then
            dx_10ms = dx_10ms * 2
            dy_10ms = dy_10ms * 2
         end
         local duration = recoil_sequence[j]
         repeat
            Sleep(10)
            if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
            local dt = math.min(GetRunningTime() - tm, duration)
            duration, tm = duration - dt, tm + dt
            x, y = x + dt/10 * dx_10ms, y + dt/10 * dy_10ms
            local int_x, int_y = math.floor(x), math.floor(y)
            x, y = x - int_x, y - int_y
            MoveMouseRelative(int_x, int_y)
         until duration == 0
         if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: okay this seems a lot more complex than my basic understanding takes me, how can I add to this? how can I make more steps in the mouse movements? is there a way I can add randomizations into this? P.S you're a wizard lol

Comment: `how can I make more steps in the mouse movements? ` - Just add more lines in recoil_table["AK47"]  `add randomizations into this?` - What exactly should be randomized?  Please show your old script with randomization.

Comment: as I'm still new to coding I'm not sure on randomization at all, I'm not even sure if I need it at all. was more of a question of confirmation more than anything lol. I've been working of the edit of my code that you sent me and added more lines to the table and now it works nicely so thank you very much for that. my next task is to add other guns. how can i take my script and add multiple weapons? can i copy the same codes and edit things so when i press another g button on my mouse i can use a different weapon?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: That's perfect thank you, I have everything i need now to build the script the way I want to. Quick question... This part of the script you wrote for me  "0, 0.5, 1000," Is there any reason that its 0.5? my understanding is that MoveMouseRelative cannot work with decimals. is it the math.floor that makes this work by rounding it up or down? I'm only asking this because the new weapon I added has to much recoil compensation with 0, 3, 120, and not enough with 0, 2, 120,. i was wondering if there's a way to get it just right without altering mouse sensitivity

Comment: Yes, you can use fractional numbers to slightly change the speed.  `MoveMouseRelative` will get only integer argument because of math.floor.  The number 0.5 in my example is just to show that fractional numbers are allowed.

Comment: so 0, 2.5, 120 is faster than 0, 2, 120 but slower than 0, 3, 120 on the y axis? and will this be compatible with the code you helped me write.       also I'm going to edit my original code to what i have now just to make things a bit more clear for those who are helping with my project

Comment: `so 0, 2.5, 120 is faster than 0, 2, 120 but slower than 0, 3, 120 on the y axis?` - Yes.  Try and see.

Comment: works perfectly, I'm shocked to be honest and wish I never sooner. Just to clear a something up... does the language itself read the fractional number and slow down the movement of the mouse to compensate for only being to move a pixel at a time or is it a strange biproduct? I'd like to know more about how this works exactly. I'm starting to become very interested in coding at this point :)

Comment: this behavior is intentionally enforced in lines 86-91 of the script

Comment: right... so now i have all the weapon functions and recoil movements coded in nicely. the last thing I'd like to implement is modifiers for attachments. there is a specific way I have in mind on how I would like it to work but not sure if it is even possible. is modifying the values of both a standard and a crouch table by a certain amount possible by selecting a key? if so can 3 separate keys be used to alternate between 3 attachments? for example one scope gives +2.0x in zoom and one gives -0.5x in zoom, is there a way of coding a multiplied and divided variant into the lines I already have

Comment: or will i have to add a totally new function such as (for example) local AK47SCOPE_MOUSE = 8 recoil_table["AK47SCOPE"] = { } recoil_table["AK47SCOPE_crouch"] = {} Ideally id like the convenience of simply selecting a key to make the script know that the scope is in use

Comment: just for clarification I mean buttons to toggle between... I didn't word it very well. Also the properties of each scope are the same regardless of what gun they are equipped to so maybe a solution is something along the lines of if a key is toggled then apply x amount  more/less

Comment: So, you want to introduce another modifier similar to crouch: when you keep `Alt` key pressed the mouse movement speed is x2, isn't it?

Comment: Essentially yes, but only if it can be toggled and multiple options can be added

Comment: Still not clear: which buttons should control which features and how exactly?

Comment: Maybe F-keys or arrow keys. Which ever maybe possible

Comment: Should F-key be "toggle" (press again to turn off) or "keep-pressed"?

Comment: yes toggle would be best suited

Comment: so is this something that isnt possible and i'll have to just make additional weapons to overcome the issue?

Comment: Answer updated.  Key G1 toggles speedX2 ON/OFF

Comment: could you take a look at the post again? I've updated it a bit and could use your help again. thanks

Comment: You can make several modifiers similar to `SpeedX2`.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes but unfortunately it didn’t work as I had anticipated so looks like I’ll have to write tables for each individual attachment, I’d just like to be able to have toggle keys that work in conjunction with which profile is activated so I have the ability to have most guns mapped to the mouse buttons

Comment: `it didn’t work as I had anticipated` - What is wrong?

Comment: The issue is with making the recoil faster or slower in attempts to change the recoil with which ever attachments I want to use. It’s not as accurate as a dedicated table

Comment: So, you just need different speed factor for each weapon?

Comment: No I need 3 variants of each table that can be toggled with lock keys and still work in conjunction with the crouch modifier, for example if gun1 is selected and caps lock is on then = gun1scope… if gun1 is selected and scroll lock is on then = gun1reddot

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: could i speak with you via discord so you can help me iron out any problems I'm dealing with? I can make a donation for your time if need be

Comment: i need a fresh canvas, there's so many comments here now I'm becoming overwhelmed lol. my rep isn't high enough to pm so I dropped you an email